Unable to resolve host <URL>: No address associated with hostname
I made a simple weather widget that calls the API with RetroFit. It works well on emulators and my Samsung S22 Ultra, except for my S24 Ultra which keeps getting the error.
Both phones have pretty much the same settings with the same Android version (14).
Not sure if mobile data has anything to do with it but it was working fine until I disconnected the WiFi and was using data. However, reconnecting to Wifi doesn't work, it just cant resolve the API's hostname.
I have tried:

Using either Wifi or Data
Changing DNS to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8
Restarting my phone
Clearing app data / Reinstalling

Nothing worked

If you use the URL in a Web browser on that device, does it work? If the answer is "no", then this is not a problem with your programming. If the answer is "yes", then we would need a [mcve] to advise you on whether there is something in your code that might contribute to the problem.
